# Creating indices of a string in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

How would I search through a string to create an index of each occurrence of a string?

For example:

"Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run! See how they run!"

I need to create an index each time "ee" begins.

Comment: string.IndexOf returns the position of "ee"

Comment: Regex can return all matches and you can store them in index tables (whatever form of your table may be)

Comment: right, but only the first "ee". How do I get each "ee" position to be returned? I'm assuming I need a loop, but I can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: Does "eeee" have two or have three occurrences of "ee" according to how you want to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to make a search.

```
    Dim test = "Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run! See how they run!"
    Dim search As String = "ee"
    Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(test, search)
        indexes.Add(m.Index)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

string.IndexOf has an overload that allows to scan the string searching for a substring

```
Dim test = "Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run! See how they run!"
Dim indexes = new List(Of Integer)()
Dim pos = -1
while(true)
    pos = test.IndexOf("ee", pos + 1)
    if pos >= 0 then
        indexes.Add(pos)
        pos += 1
    Else
        Exit While
    End if
End While

For each i in indexes
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

Just for fun, another version that doesn't use at all IndexOf

```
Sub Main()
    Dim test = "Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run! See how they run!"
    Dim targetValue = "mice"
    Dim indexes() = AllIndexOf(test, targetValue)
    for each i in indexes
       Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
End Sub    



Function AllIndexOf(source as string, search as string) as Integer()
    Dim positions = new List(Of Integer)()
    for i = 0 to source.Length-1

        Dim y = i
        Dim x = 0
        while(x < search.Length And y+x < source.Length)

           Dim c = source(y+x)
           if c <> search(x) then
                Exit While
            End If
           x +=1
        End While
        if x = search.Length Then
            positions.Add(y)
        End If
    Next
    return positions.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

Yet another solution just for the hell of it!

```
Dim test = "Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run! See how they run!"
Dim search As String = "ee"
Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)
Dim i As Integer = test.IndexOf(search)
Do While (i <> -1)
    indexes.Add(i)
    i = test.IndexOf(search, i + 1)
Loop
```